# Why does "TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable" occur?

Tags: python

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3]
>>> l2 = [1,2]
>>> assert all(any(x in l1 for x in l2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

I want to check whether l2 is included in l1.

Comment: `any()` just returns `True` or `False`. Why are you passing that to `all()`?

Comment: I want to see for every element in l2, it is also in l1.

Comment: Why any element? Shouldn't it be every element in l2? That's what `all()` does.

Comment: Yes, I meant every element in l2, it's also in l1

Comment: Both `any` and `all` require *iterables* of values, not just a single value. E.g. `any(True)` is an error, but `any([True])` return `True`.

Comment: I think I know how all and any work in python now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `all()`, not `any()`.

```
assert(all(x in l1 for x in l2))
```

You can also use set operations:

```
assert(set(l2) <= set(l1))
```

Answer (score 2):

`any` works this way:

> Return True if bool(x) is True for any x in the iterable.

So `any(x in l1 for x in l2)` returns a `bool`, which is not a proper argument for `all`.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over `l2`, and check that each value is in `l1`.

```
assert all(x in l1 for x in l2)
```

Since `int`s are hashable, you can create a set and check if it is a subset of the other list (`set.issubset` can handle arbitrary iterable values).

```
assert set(l2).issubset(l1)
```